# $f$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an holomorphic function, defined in a neighbourhood of $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Assume $f(\partial\mathbb{D})\in\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,\infty)$.

Show that $f$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{D}$.

How can I proove this? I have unfortunately no idea.

Comment: So far, 36 questions and only 7 accepted answers? You must be really picky! Some day people will stop answering your questions.

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula should be relevant.

Comment: @JohnHughes: Indeed I have, it's a strategy of mine to educate users to accept answers (when these are worth being accepted, of course). I don't think that blindly accepting answers to all the question is good, but 7 out of 36 was not reasonable, especially given that some of the received answers were really good.

Comment: @AreaMan you mean the argument principle) ?

Comment: @JohnHughes : It might be a bit weird but [it works](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/337060/n-sch)

Comment: I should have added "Yay!" I'm all for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $f$ has no zeroes or poles on $\partial\mathbb{D}$ we may apply the argument principle to $f$ on this contour. Inside $\partial\mathbb{D}$, $f$ has no poles so by the argument principle, $\int_{\partial\mathbb{D}}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=2\pi iN$ where $N$ is the number of zeroes. By a change of variables, $\int_{\partial\mathbb{D}}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\int_{f(\partial\mathbb{D})}\frac{1}{w}\,dw$ where this latter expression is the winding number of the path $f(\partial\mathbb{D})$ around the origin. This must be zero because $f(\partial\mathbb{D})$ never crosses $[0,\infty)$. More explicitly, because $f(\partial\mathbb{D})\in\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,\infty)$ we may define a holomorphic branch of the logarithm that contians $f(\partial\mathbb{D})$. This logarithm will serve as a primitive of $\frac{1}{w}$ so its integral around the closed curve $f(\partial\mathbb{D})$ will vanish.

Comment: $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz$ is automatically well defined ?  $|f(e^{it})|$ is assumed continuous so if it wasn't bounded below there would be a $t_0$ such that $|f(e^{it_0})| = 0$ contradicting that $f(e^{it}) \not \in [0,\infty)$

Comment: Good point. I have amended my answer to address this.